# How can I conditionally change a CSS class based on Controller action result with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc

I've seen some comparable posts on this, but nothing quite that mimics the behavior I am looking for. With my simple ASP.Net app, the results of a Controller method are stored in TempData when the form is submitted. Based on the existence of a value in that slot,  I want to change (set) the CSS class of a  tag (to change the color). I have the following View code that does work:

```
 <p>
    <input type="submit" name="submitAction" value="Test Connection" />
    @if (TempData["connectionResults"] != null)
    {
        <span class="@(TempData["connectionResults"].ToString() 
                         == "Connection successful" ?
                            "dbConnectionSuccess" : "dbConnectionFail")">
           @TempData["connectionResults"]
        </span> 
    }
    </p>
```

My question is, is there a more elegant way of doing this with javascript or jQuery? There are a lot of posts on SO that do comparable things, but not on the result of an action call in a controller.

Thanks!

Comment: Do this on the server side, kinda obvious you know.

Comment: No, there isn't a more elegant way of doing it with JavaScript. Not to mention that using client-side code that executes on page load to do something you could (and should) have done server-side doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Doesn't that mix concerns? Why should my Controller class know anything about the way a value is displayed? It should only provide the value, not the presentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, I think I figured out what you guys meant by executing the logic server-side. I thought you meant to return the class name from the controller...all I think you meant was return the result of the test from the controller. This is what I ended up with:

```
<p>
    <input type="submit" name="submitAction" id="testConnection" value="Test Connection" />
    @if (@Model.IsDbConnectionSuccessful != null)
    {
        if (@Model.IsDbConnectionSuccessful.Value)
        {
            <span class="dbConnectionSuccess">Connection successful</span>                    
        }
        else
        {
            <span class="dbConnectionFail">Connection  Unsuccessful</span>                     
        }               
    }
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with JQuery within document.ready. E.g.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     var resultString= '@TempData["connectionResults"].ToString()';

     if (resultString != null && resultString.toLowerCase() == 'connection successful') {
          $('#spanID').addClass('dbConnectionSuccess');
     } else {
          $('#spanID').addClass('dbConnectionFail');
     }
});
```

You'd have to give your 'span' tag an ID. This would also have to be within your .cshtml file for the @TempData to be processed by the server.

This is tidier than the above IMO but still not a great solution.

Comment: I think there is some confusion on what is stored in TempData...it's the success/fail value of the test "Connection successful" or "Connection failed", not the name of the class to set. I have a conditional statement in my code to check the value, then set the class based on that value. I changed the spacing a bit to hopefully help show it a bit better.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something fundamental, I don't think so. In your example, className would be set to 'Connection Successful' for example. That is not correct, it should be 'dbConnectionSuccess'

Comment: OK I see.. rather than className the variable should be called something such as 'result'. Other than this the logic is correct.

Comment: Yeah - the logic is correct. Still though, as you said, it's not really a good solution since the logic should be executed on the server. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Logic for deciding css classes should be client side. I think using JQuery as above is fine for such a scenario. You do not want to be in a position where you send a css class name down to the client, I wouldn't think. However.. on which event you called the above JQuery is important as document.ready may not be correct.